# How to print the full data coming in [object Object] in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have a script to print the network response of a page using the Chrome Dev tools. The script is like this :

```
 browser.cdp('Network', 'enable')
    browser.on('Network.responseReceived', (params) => {
        console.log(`Loaded ${params.response}`)
    })
    browser.url('https://www.google.com')
})
```

But in console.log, it prints like

> '[object Object]'

I tried different methods like -

```
  console.log('Status: ' + util.inspect(`${params.response}`))
  console.log("Session: %j", `${params.response}`);
  console.log(`Loaded ${params.response}`)
  console.dir(`${params.response}`, { depth: null });
```

Still no luck. How can print all the contents coming inside that object. I need to print and also save all the contents in that object array to a har file. Please let me know how i can do that.

Comment: try console.log(`Loaded JSON.stringify(params.response))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the objects are not logged deeply. Probably because could exist circular properties. When you write:

```js
console.log(`Loaded ${params.response}`) // Loaded [object Object]
```

Its similar to:

```js
console.log(params.response.toString()) // [object Object]
```

Instead, use `JSON.stringify()`:

```js
const object = {property: 'value'}

console.log(object.toString()) // [object Object]
console.log(JSON.stringify(object)) // {property: "value"}
```

Also you can specify the format of the output format for better reading:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(object), null, 2) // Format with 2 spaces identation

//  {
//    "property": "value"
//  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this options.

The first and easiest one is if you spread the object.
`console.log("Loaded ${params.response}", {...params.response})`.

But if you prefer, you can iterate all the objects properties like so.

```js
 browser.cdp('Network', 'enable')
        browser.on('Network.responseReceived', (params) => {
            if (params && typeof params.response === "object") {
                const {response} = params;
                Objec.keys(response).forEach(key => {
                     if (typeof response[key] === "object" && Objec.keys(response[key]).length > 0) {
                         const subObject = response[key];
                         Object.keys(subObject).forEach(subKey => {
                             console.log('subObject[subKey]', subObject[subKey])
                         });
                     } else {
                       console.log(`${response[key]}`, response[key])
                     }
                })
            }
            console.log(`Loaded ${params.response}`, {...params.response})
        })
        browser.url('https://www.google.com')
    })
```

Comment: Could you tell me how can I write the contents of {response} to a file.

Comment: it depends if this response happens on yow client. javascript on clients AKA browsers do not have access to the file system. but if this is on the express side
```
const {response} = params;
const write = fs.createWriteStream(path)
write.write(response)

```

Comment: or you can use witson